# Unexpected token u, NEXTJS13

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, nextjs

Estoy realizando una aplicación, para dicha aplicación uso el hook de CreateContext de react, por ende en el archivo donde lo creo uso "use client" debido a que me encuentro usando NextJs13. El problema radica en cuando desde otro archivo, busco obtener el contexto, no carga la pantalla, se queda en blanco y me indica el siguiente error:

SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse ()

. Decidi cambiar a una versión de NextJs13 -> 13.2.4, para mi sorpresa en dicha versión no pasaba el error. Desconozco que pueda ser.

El codigo es el siguiente.

Layout:

````
```
import { TaskProvider } from '@/context/TasksContext'
import './globals.css'

export const metadata = {
title: 'Create Next App',
description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}
```
````

Context:

```
    "use client"
    import { createContext, useContext } from "react";
    
    export const TaskContext = createContext();
    
    /*export const useTask = () => {
      const context = useContext(TaskContext);
      if (!context) throw new Error("useTasks must be used within a provider")
      return context
    }*/
    
    export const TaskProvider = ({children}) => {
      const tasks = [];
      return <TaskContext.Provider value={tasks}>{children}</TaskContext.Provider>
    }
```

About:

```
    "use client"
    import { useContext } from "react";
    import { TaskContext } from "@/context/TasksContext";
    
    export default function Page() {
      const values = useContext(TaskContext);
      console.log(values);
      return (
        <div>about page</div>
      );
    }
```

¡Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: Intenta "use-client" en todos los archivos enlazados